# How to prevent Mac Outlook from inserting line breaks in sent plain text emails?

Tags: ms-office

When I send plain text emails with Mac Outlook, line breaks are automatically inserted. This is annoying for several reasons. (1) long URLs are split over multiple lines which confuses readers; (2) personalised line formatting breaks. Others share the problem (e.g., [here](http://blog.yimingliu.com/2011/12/25/outlook-2011-still-mangling-plaintext-emails/) and [here](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/et020306.htm))

How can I prevent Mac Outlook from inserting line breaks in plain text emails?